# Why a Python function copied from class access the class data from outside?

Tags: python

How come function x can access the "self" of some object it's not part of???
See the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class A(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.a = 1

  def doit(self):
    print self.a

a = A()
x = a.doit
x()
```

See:

```
$ ./classes.py 
1
$
```

Comment: `x = a.doit` isn't a "copy" of anything.  What makes you think it's a copy?  Where have you seen code like this that says that a copy is being made?  What lead you to believe there was copying going in?

Answer (score 4):

If you call `x()`, it simply resolves to calling `a.doit()`, which is no problem at all to access the contents of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with something call `binding`. The short and stupid explanation: the method will "remember" (it is bound to) where it was created and operate in that context.

The longer explanation goes into how closures are doing the same thing, and it does things like cites Alonzo Church and some pretty nifty stuff like locally defined functions and classes. But the long and the short will always be that it is simply recalling its context.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `instance.attr`, and the attribute is a *function*, python does something extra; it returns the function as a "method", with the `self` parameter preset to the instance.  In the case that you instead do `someclass.attr`; the same attribute but on a class instead of an instance of the class; python will still return a method, but without binding `self`.

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.a = 1
...   def doit(self):
...     print self.a
... 
>>> A
<class '__main__.A'>
```

The method, as accessed from the class

```
>>> A.doit
<unbound method A.doit>
>>> print repr(A.doit.im_self)
None
```

`self` not yet bound to anything

An instance of `A`

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0x7fa13456ca50>
```

`self` is bound for `a.doit`

```
>>> a.doit
<bound method A.doit of <__main__.A object at 0x7fa13456ca50>>
>>> print repr(a.doit.im_self)
<__main__.A object at 0x7fa13456ca50>
```

it's the same object:

```
>>> a.doit.im_self is a
True
```